# How to setattribute to a page generated by javascript using VB.net?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, post

I found out that this page is generated by javascript. So my Attempt to use getElementByID of WEBBrowser in VB.NET is not working since the page below is generated by  javascript.

https://oms.itradenetwork.com/2/login/logon.cfm

can someone show me how to set value to the OuterHTML?

I can see it has an element

```
<input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="UserName" name="UserName"...
```

and

```
<input type="password" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="Password" name="Password"
```

and

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen32" class=" x-btn-text">Logon</button>
```

I am hoping I can simulate in VB.net to enter this credential and simulate the login button.

Here is attempt in VB.net, where the GetElementByID is failing.. because at the time Document is still in JavaScript. I assume I  need to get the OuterHTML . but can I set value attribute and GetElementByID if I get OuterHTML? and furthermore to click the login button?

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim wBro As WebBrowser

 Private Sub dothis()
        wBro = New WebBrowser
        wBro.Navigate("https://oms.itradenetwork.com/2/login/logon.cfm")
        AddHandler wBro.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Me.wBroComplete
 End Sub

 Private Sub wBroComplete()
        Dim eM1 As HtmlElement
        eM1 = wBro.Document.GetElementById("UserName")
        If eM1 IsNot Nothing Then
            MsgBox("hi")
        End If
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: *I found out that this page is generated by javascript. So my Attempt to getElementByID is not working since the page is in javascript.* That makes no sense. `getElementById()` is a JavaScript API.  Do you mean that the page is generated by VB?

Comment: I am using getElementByID of webBrower Object in VB.net. but It is not getting the element because the page is in JavaScript.

Comment: if you view source on https://oms.itradenetwork.com/2/login/logon.cfm you will see that it is all javascript. But when you inspect element in chrome you can see the OuterHTML result